# Maven: Using Java 8 libraries in applications instrumented with retrolambda-maven-plugin and DEX-ed with android-maven-plugin

Tags: android, maven, java-8, android-maven-plugin, retrolambda

I have written a small set of minilibraries for my internal use. This is set is built using Maven. The libraries are targetted for "regular" Java, GWT and Android. Some of them are written in Java 8 because I hadn't any intention to run them on GWT or Android, thus the other libraries are written in old Java 6 to support these two. I have a plan of full migration of my libs to Java 8 (in terms of language features), and I succeeded to run Java 8 rewritten libraries on not yet released GWT 2.8.0. However, I cannot make the Java 8 rewritten libs to compile for Android applications. The issue is that Retrolambda (the `retrolambda-maven-plugin` plugin) seems to be able to process the current Maven module classes only, and fully ignores the dependency classes. Thus, the `android-maven-plugin` breaks the target application build with:

```
[INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
[INFO] ...while parsing foo/bar/FooBar.class
```

The `retrolambda-maven-plugin` is configured as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.orfjackal.retrolambda</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrolambda-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-main</goal>
                <goal>process-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <defaultMethods>true</defaultMethods>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to configure the Retrolambda plugin to process the library classes as well so all dependencies? Or maybe I just could use another bytecode processing tool?

---

**UPDATE #1**

I think I'm wrong about the Retrolambda fail. Digging into it a little more, I've figured out that `android-maven-plugin` can be blamed for it because it picks the not instrumented JAR files from the Maven repository directly, and not from the `target` directory. Enabling verbose logging discovered this pseudo-code command invoked by the `android-maven-plugin`:

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/java
-Xmx1024M
-jar "$ANDROID_HOME/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/lib/dx.jar"
--dex
--output=$BUILD_DIRECTORY/classes.dex
$BUILD_DIRECTORY/classes
$M2_REPO/foo1/bar1/0.1-SNAPSHOT/bar1-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
$M2_REPO/foo2/bar2/0.1-SNAPSHOT/bar2-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
$M2_REPO/foo3/bar3/0.1-JAVA-8-SNAPSHOT/bar3-0.1-JAVA-8-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My idea is executing the `maven-dependency-plugin` plugin to obtain those three artifacts into the `$BUILD_DIRECTORY/classes` directory to let the `retrolambda-maven-plugin` instrument the dependencies. Let's say:

**STEP 1: Copy the dependencies to the target directory**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**STEP 2: Instrument the copied dependencies using Retrolambda**

*Invoke `retrolambda-maven-plugin`*

**STEP 3: Compile the DEX file**

*Invoke `android-maven-plugin` excluding the dependencies that were copied to the target directory, because they are all supposed to be located in the target directory*

But this fails too, because I can't find a way to exclude artifacts from being DEXed with the `android-maven-plugin`.

How do I suppress the artifacts from being fetched from the repository where they are stored in non-instrumented state?

My plugins configuration:

- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10
- net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda-maven-plugin:2.0.2
- com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.9.0-rc.3

---

**UPDATE #2**

The Simpligility team has released Android Maven Plugin 4.4.1 featuring the scenario described below. See more at the plugin [changelog](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/changelog.html#_4_4_1_released_2016_01_28).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Example scenario can be found at http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/instrumentation.html

Comment: great question and solution! saved my day...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Four months later, after having some time for investigation, I have finally made it work. First of all, the crucial thing about the solution is patching `android-maven-plugin`. I have forked the original plugin at GitHub and added a few configuration filter options that allow to include or exclude artifacts by group IDs, artifact IDs, and their respective versions.  This is very important to configure `retrolambda-maven-plugin`. The overall workflow is basically the same as I noted in the question. Here it is:

- `maven-compiler-plugin` Enable Java 8 language features support. Optional, as the main objective is processing Java 8 dependencies.
- `maven-dependency-plugin` Unpack ALL Java 8 dependencies to the current project build target directory for the further processing.
- `retrolambda-maven-plugin` Process all the obtained class files using the Retrolambda plugin.
- `android-maven-plugin` Compile the DEX and APK files with the fork of the original `android-maven-plugin`.

Installing the fork:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# The last upstream merge revision
PLUGIN_COMMIT=a79e45bc0721bfea97ec139311fe31d959851476

# Clone the fork
git clone https://github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/android-maven-plugin.git

# Ensure proper revision
cd android-maven-plugin
git checkout $PLUGIN_COMMIT

# Build the forked plugin, no tests
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# Clone plugin JAR
cd target
cp android-maven-plugin-4.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar android-maven-plugin-4.3.1-SNAPSHOT-$PLUGIN_COMMIT.jar

# Clone and modify pom.xml
cp ../pom.xml pom-$PLUGIN_COMMIT.xml
sed -i "s/<version>4.3.1-SNAPSHOT<\\/version>/<version>4.3.1-SNAPSHOT-$PLUGIN_COMMIT<\\/version>/g" pom-$PLUGIN_COMMIT.xml

# Update the plugin descriptor
unzip android-maven-plugin-4.3.1-SNAPSHOT-$PLUGIN_COMMIT.jar META-INF/maven/plugin.xml
sed -i "s/<version>4.3.1-SNAPSHOT<\\/version>/<version>4.3.1-SNAPSHOT-$PLUGIN_COMMIT<\\/version>/g" META-INF/maven/plugin.xml
zip android-maven-plugin-4.3.1-SNAPSHOT-$PLUGIN_COMMIT.jar META-INF/maven/plugin.xml

# Install the plugin
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -DpomFile=pom-$PLUGIN_COMMIT.xml -Dfile=android-maven-plugin-4.3.1-SNAPSHOT-$PLUGIN_COMMIT.jar
```

Done. Next, register the fork in your `pom.xml` and configure the build plugins:

```xml
<!-- enable Java 8 for the current module -->

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<!-- unpack Java 8 dependency classes to the current module build directory -->

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    <includeGroupIds>foo-group,bar-group,baz-group</includeGroupIds>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<!-- Convert Java 8 to Java 6 -->

<plugin>
    <groupId>net.orfjackal.retrolambda</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrolambda-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-main</goal>
                <goal>process-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <defaultMethods>true</defaultMethods>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<!-- DEXify and build the APK excluding the Java 8 dependencies as they are already processed -->

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1-SNAPSHOT-a79e45bc0721bfea97ec139311fe31d959851476</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/android/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
        <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/android/assets</assetsDirectory>
        <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/android/res</resourceDirectory>
        <sdk>
            <platform>19</platform>
        </sdk>
        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        <proguard>
            <skip>true</skip>
            <config>${project.basedir}/proguard.conf</config>
        </proguard>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>foo-group</exclude>
            <exclude>bar-group</exclude>
            <exclude>baz-group</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

It should work.

---

Update

Recently I patched the fork for the Proguard Maven mojo.

Update 2

The `android-maven-plugin` repository owner [merged](https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/commit/e56d8daa65a61b1d16f12819500a3aabcb32ba89) my commits, so the artifact filtering is scheduled for the next version.

Comment: Any luck with GWT+Retrolambda?

Comment: @Namek these components are unrelated. GWT processes the original source code only, whilst Retrolambda processes byte code. GWT 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT can work with Java 8 lambda expressions pretty stable.

Comment: Thanks for your great job! I hope you help solve my issue with your suggestion:
I have an _aar_ android library which I am depended to. As you might guess, the build fails because maven-dependency-plugin can not unpack this type of artifacts:

**Unpacking \[path]\someLibrary.aar to \[path]\target\classes.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:unpack-dependencies (default) on project aquilax-dist-droid-operator: Unknown archiver type: No such archiver: "aar".**

Comment: @Amin Yes, I have faced with exactly the same issue. There is no known to me elegant way to resolve the issue, but if you're fine with `maven-antrun-plugin`, you can refer a question I asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940455/how-do-i-unpack-aar-dependency-classes-in-maven

Comment: @Amin I've also documented a sample AAR-scenario that also has been [merged](https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/commit/bf39e03d392ba9e32a4a05bfcf32c44eafa71a2b) to the master branch. Thus, you won't need custom local plugin management in the nearest future.

Comment: @Lyubomyr Shaydariv, thank you for your reply. Yet another question I have, if you don't mind. Is there any way to exclude **all** the dependencies which are copied to current project's build/classes directory (using the patched android-maven-plugin)?

Comment: @Amin if I understand you correctly, then yes: you could use `<skipDependencies>true</skipDependencies>`. There are some more filtering options (where: 1) explicit rules override implicit; 2) includes override excludes; 3) concrete artifacts override concrete artifact types): `skipDependencies` (boolean), `artifactTypeSet` with child `includes` and `excludes` ('jar', 'aar', etc), and `artifactSet` with child `includes` and `excludes` as well.

Comment: @Amin here are the commits that bring new configuration options: `skipDependencies`: https://github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/android-maven-plugin/commit/79b0c308283d1bac04ba928f5c99e5c66d37507d ; `artifactTypeSet`: https://github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/android-maven-plugin/commit/803fced310821331a8fa37b2e8b5ab17e9cabe25 , `artifactSet`: https://github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/android-maven-plugin/commit/d6224e355080d9df3cf05ae4edaf1d0c40062fdc , and `includes` over `excludes` https://github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/android-maven-plugin/commit/e624aab92ed89751c3bd9dffc8ecda75c1f29e34

Comment: @Amin and, since these all the changes have been merged to the upstream project, you can switch to the original project by cloning it as I ocasionally sync my fork with the upstream now. I recommend you to use the very last revision, because the `a79e45bc0721bfea97ec139311fe31d959851476` revision I specified in the answer is somewhat broken (it does not work with ProGuard causing some issues -- fixed in `ab2e6706b64dd31a33ece3de77f42c2b2e8606d7` and later). This is probably all I can share.

Comment: @Lyubomyr Shaydariv, Unfortunately the exclude tag does not work for me at all. I am receiving the same error with/without using <excludes>. I will apply you latest solution to see if it works.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv, and Would you please let me know how/where I would see an example of using <artifactSet> with child excludes? I can not find any information on the web page (http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/). Is this form OK?
**<artifactSet>  <excludes>    <exclude>*:maven-core</exclude</excludes></artifactSet>**
Many thanks in advance

Comment: @Amin Unfortunately no. Wildcards are not supported. The general syntax of an include/exclude element content is `[groupId[:artifactId[:versionId]]]`, where in-brackets text is optional. Thus you can filter by groupId, by groupId/artifactId, or by groupId/artifactId/version (empty values are simply ignored). You probably might find a bit more in the original PR discussion here: https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/pull/632

Comment: @Amin Sorry for poor documentation, fortunately it can be found in JavaDoc that's probably might be supplied along with the plugin and probably could be seen in an IDE (really, not sure). Ah, by the way, enable the `-X` switch in Maven command-line to get Maven verbose output and obtain the filtered dependencies list. Hope this switch helps. :)

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I did take a look at the source code of the commit-links you provided previously, and that helped a lot (sorry to inform you late). Thank to your previous job and your present responsiveness, I managed to build my project :)
BTW, the bash could be shortened to:
**#!/bin/bash [\n]
git clone https://github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/android-maven-plugin.git[\n]
cd android-maven-plugin[\n]
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true[\n]
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -DpomFile=pom.xml -Dfile=target/android-maven-plugin-4.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

Comment: @Amin I'm glad I could help you out. :)

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv  Hey, its me again. Using gradle, the same issue appears. In other word, one might to unpack dependencies to retrolambda them. I want to know if you have any probable experience with that too?

Comment: @Amin, no, I don't use Gradle.